# C3.js combination chart with time series - tooltip not functional

Tags: c3.js

I've been trying for 3 days to get this chart to display the way I want it to. Everything was working 100% until I realized the grouped bar chart numbers were off.

Example: When the bottom bar value equals 10 and the top bar value equals 20, the top of the grouped bar read 30. This is the default behavior, but not how I want to represent my data. I want the top of the grouped bar to read whatever the highest number is, which lead me to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvn3y0q6/5/) representing the data exactly how I wanted to.

After refactoring my logic, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/NightOwlPrgmr/114r25z5/) is what I have so far. As you can see the timeseries line is broken up and the tooltip is not rendering the group of data being hovered over.

> My questions:
>
> 1) How to get the tooltip to render all three data points (qty, price, searches)
>
> 2) How to solidify the timeseries line so it's not disconnected

Any help would be greatly appreciated so I can move on from this 3 day headache!

Below is most of my code - excluding the JSON array for brevity, which is obtainable at my jsfiddle link above. Thank you in advance for your time.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
        bindto: '#chart',
        data: {
            x: 'x-axis',
            type: 'bar',
            json: json,
            xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d',
            keys: {
                x: 'x-axis',
                y: 'searches',
                value: ['qty', 'searches', 'price']
            },
            types: {
                searches: 'line'
            },
            groups: [
                ['qty', 'price']
            ],
            axes: {
                qty: 'y',
                searches: 'y2'
            },
            names: {
                qty: 'Quantity',
                searches: 'Searches',
                price: 'Price ($)'
            },
            colors: {
                price: 'rgb(153, 153, 153)',
                qty: 'rgb(217, 217, 217)',
                searches: 'rgb(255, 127, 14)'
            }
        },
        bar: {
            width: {
                ratio: 0.60
            }
        },
        axis: {
            x: {
                type: 'timeseries',
                label: { text: 'Timeline', position: 'outer-right' },
                tick: {
                    format: '%Y-%m-%d'
                }
            },
            y: {
                type: 'bar',
                label: {
                    text: 'Quantity / Price',
                    position: 'outer-middle'
                }
            },
            y2: {
                show: true,
                label: {
                    text: 'Searches',
                    position: 'outer-middle'
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            grouped: true,
            contents: function(d, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color) {
                var data = this.api.data.shown().map(function(series) {
                    var matchArr = series.values.filter(function(datum) {
                        return datum.value != undefined && datum.x === d[0].x;
                    });
                    if (matchArr.length > 0) {
                        matchArr[0].name = series.id;
                        return matchArr[0];
                    }
                });
                return this.getTooltipContent(data, defaultTitleFormat, defaultValueFormat, color);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

1) If I got it right, you want tooltip to show all values, even if some of them are null.
Null values are hidden by default. You can replace them with zero (if it is suitable for your task) and thus make them visible.

Also, it seems to me that there is a shorter way to get grouped values:

```
var data = chart.internal.api.data().map(function(item) {
  var row = item.values[d[0].index];       // get data for selected index
  if (row.value === null) row.value = 0;   // make null visible
  return row;
});
```

2) I think you are talking about [line.connectNull](http://c3js.org/reference.html#line-connectNull) option:

```
line: {
  connectNull: true
}
```

---

**UPDATE**
Looks like having duplicate keys breaks work of *api.data()* method.
You need to change json structure to make keys **unique**:

**Before:**

```
var json = [
  {"x-axis":"2017-07-17","qty":100},
  {"x-axis":"2017-07-17","price":111},
  {"x-axis":"2017-07-17","searches":1},
  {"x-axis":"2017-07-18","qty":200},
  {"x-axis":"2017-07-18","price":222},
  {"x-axis":"2017-07-18","searches":2}
];
```

**After:**

```
var json = [
  {"x-axis":"2017-07-17","qty":100,"price":111,"searches":1},
  {"x-axis":"2017-07-18","qty":200,"price":222,"searches":2}
];
```

See **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/ge7keha4/2/)**.

Comment: Wow, rock on man that is very close! I like the connectNull option, that works good and the tooltip is actually displaying now! However, I apologize for not being clear, but I don't want to return null values in the tooltip. I believe the purpose of the filter method was to remove any null values as well as to not include the data point if datum.x is not equal to d[0].x (one holds the date value being hovered on while the other is all the data points in the chart). Ideally, hovering over a bar should group the qty, price, and searches for that day in the tooltip.

Comment: The only way I see is to make json keys unique, see update.

Comment: Yes, this is how I originally had the json structured; however, then the bars read incorrectly (IMO). I understand this is the default behavior of a "stacked" bar chart, but I don't want the two (qty and price) to "add" up - so to speak. I want them to sort of overlay one another, so the light grey bar on the 2017-07-17 bar should be at 100 while the dark grey should be at 111 - not 211. Not sure if this is possible or not, but I saw it worked for the fiddle I linked to in my OP, so I thought I'd give it a try. Any thoughts on this?